# javamail - 504 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

i will send mail via java mail in my webapp. i wrote a code and test it via gmail account and it works fine. then i replace my host smtp detail with gmail information and test it. oops it return my a following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 504 5.5.2 <rasta-PC>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2099)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:1490)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:662)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at util.MailUtil.sendViaSSL(MailUtil.java:43)
    at control.member.AddMemberControl.add(AddMemberControl.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at filter.CheckLoginFilter.doFilter(CheckLoginFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

you can see my code in the following:

```
public static void sendViaSSL(final MailServerDetail msd,String to, String subject, String text){

    Properties props=new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.hostname");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl", "true");                 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "5000");             
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "5000"); 
    Session session=Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("My Mail Address", "Mail Password");
        }
    });

    MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); 
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("My Mail Address"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");
        message.setText(text, "UTF-8","html");

        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

can you help me solve it? 
thanks.

Comment: i test it with common-mail. but i get above error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is is usually related to an error in your name service configuration.
You can work around this problem by setting the mail.smtp.localhost property to the fully qualified host name of your machine.  See the [com.sun.mail.smtp package javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) for details.

Also, see this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: thanks it works by setting mail.smtp.localhost to my mail server smtp address.

Comment: Of course it should be set to the host name of the client machine, not the server.  The client uses the HELO command to identify itself to the server.